# javascript: Cannot set properties of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to dynamically add a new property and try a couple of ways, but nothing works.

```
var streams = new Map();
streams.set(a, { id: 123 });
streams[a].context = some not-null object;
```

This is the error.

```
Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'context')
```

So I try to pre-define context as an object.

```
var streams = new Map();
streams.set(a, { id: 123, context: {} });
streams[a].context = some not-null object;
```

But it still complains.

Comment: It doesn't complain about `context`. It complains about the *expected* object, i.e. about `streams[a]`. `streams` is `Map`, and you can access members via its  `.get` method. They are not properties. So `streams.get(a)`, not `streams[a]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var streams = new Map();
streams.set('a', { id: 123 });
streams.get('a').context = some not-null object;
```

You cannot get data like object/array from map. You have to use `get` to get the data

Answer (score 1):

Using the JavaScript [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) class, you can get properties by using the [`get`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/get) function. Here is an example:

```js
var streams = new Map();
streams.set('a', { id: 123 });
streams.get('a').context = "";     // non-null object
```

You could also use an [`Object`](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp) as so:

```js
var streams = {
    a: {
        id: 123
    }
};

streams.a.context = "";
streams['a'].context = "";        // does the same thing
```